# python save Crypto.Cipher.AES.AESCipher instance

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography

I have an Crypto.Cipher.AES.AESCipher object which i would like to save in a file.
But when i try to save it to a file i alway get the following error.
`pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle '_AES' object: <_AES object at 0x0000000002320430>`
I tried the following to save the object:
`dill.dump(object, open("save.p", "w"))`
and I also tried:
`pickle.dump(object, open("save.p", "wb"))` which also gives a similar error
I created the AES object with the following:
`BLOCK_SIZE = 32
secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)
cipher = AES.new(secret)`

This cipher i would like to save in a file and read it out again.
Is there a way to store such objects?

Comment: Why do you want to store this object? Doesn't it suffice to store the secret key?

Comment: Because this object is needed to encrypt and decrypt a string

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't creating a new object with the restored secret key suffice? That would be the sensible thing to do.

Comment: Because this cipher is random. So is it better to store the `secret` and then recreate the cipher?

Comment: I wonder where you would need such a thing. Normally, you would provide the IV yourself in order to have full control over the "randomness of the cipher".

Comment: Yeah i've changed it now. So you can provide the 'secret' yourself and then i pad it 32 bytes

Comment: You should not pad anything yourself.